# Website get indexed with and without "/" in the end of the URL - Why and how to prevent this?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, google-analytics

I have been working on a website which get indexed by google for two domains:

http://www.example.com

and

http://www.example.com**/**

an other example:

http://www.example.com/fr

and

http://www.example.com/fr/////////////  (which gets the same page, but get indexed like this).

Any idea why this is happening and how to prevent this from happening?

The main problem with this is that the information I get from google analytics cant be accurate like this.

Comment: Make sure your webserver be it nginx or apache always removes/adds the trail slash and redirect and/or you can pages from being index'd from your robots.txt file

Comment: Do you think this will help? 
`RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: @MattTheNinja Thank you! We tried some new RewriteRules and it works!